# Collecting data from array & sorting

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Four instances of the below input fields:

```
<input type='text' name='sel_id[]' size='1'/>Select Sequence 
<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='$STH->repair_id'/>Repair ID:$STH->repair_id
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
[sel_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
    )

[id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 20
        [2] => 22
        [3] => 23
    )

)
```

Instead of using brackets [] to array the sel_id and id fields from multiple instances, is it possible to somehow collect each grouping of the fields as:

```
Array([sel_id] => 4
          [id] => 1)
```

I've been struggling for days to sort the above array by the sel_id value using usort() but I'm thinking maybe there's a better way to collect the data from the form?

The full form is here and could be echo'd several times from the db:
I'd like to use the first input $int to rearrange the order of the grouped $STH->objects with the next submit.

```
$STH = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT distinct part_nomenclature FROM repairs');
foreach($STH->results() as $STH){
    $des = nl2br($STH->description); 
    $des =  htmlspecialchars_decode($STH->description,ENT_HTML5 | ENT_QUOTES);   

echo "<div class='leg'>
<input type='text' name='sel_id[]' size='1'/>Select Sequence 
<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='$STH->repair_id'/>Repair ID:$STH->repair_id
Part Nomenclature: <input type='text' size='35' value='$STH->part_nomenclature' readonly/>
Repair Name:<input type='text' size='20' value='$STH->name'/><br />
Location: <input type='text' size='20' value='$STH->location'/>
Description: <textarea rows='5' cols='100' id='text'>$des</textarea>
</div>"; 
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>";
```

Comment: Your form must have more inputs than these two. Can you post more of the form so we can see how it is structured? From the look of things, your current code should actually produce the result you want.

Comment: Oh wait, I see - you want them grouped as pairs, not with `sel_id` and `id` as sub-arrays?

Comment: Correct, grouped as pairs would be ideal and would then permit sorting by usort much easier.

Comment: Just added a new option based on your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need more information to suggest a better form approach, but to sort based on `sel_id` and the `id` array gets sorted according to that:

```
array_multisort($_POST['sel_id'], $_POST['id']);
```

Another approach might be:

```
$array = array_combine($_POST['sel_id'], $_POST['id']);
```

Now you have `sel_id` as the key and `id` as the value and can use `ksort` and/or `asort`.

To collect in pairs you need to specify the index, something like:

```
name="data[0][sel_id]"
name="data[0][id]"
name="data[1][sel_id]"
name="data[1][id]"
```

Comment: array_multisort($_POST['sel_id'], $_POST['id']); worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$_POST['sel_id']=sort($_POST['sel_id']);
$_POST['id']=sort($_POST['id']);
$na=array();
if(count($_POST['id'])>)foreach($_POST['id'] as $k=>$v){
    $na[$k]['sel_id']=$_POST['sel_id'][$k];
    $na[$k]['id']=$_POST['id'][$k];
}
var_dump($na);
```